# JQuery Accordion beforeActivate not working

Tags: jquery, accordion

Never seems to hit this code. I tried ID selector but still not firing.

I'm on JqueryUI version 1.12.1.

```
 $(".accordConditionSet").accordion({
        beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
            alert(ui.newPanel.text()); 
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Use the same concept based on Id `beforeActivate in accordion Jquery UI`

```js
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {alert(ui.newPanel.text())}});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>accordion demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget.
    Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in,
    condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros.
    Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio.</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Sed non urna. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus.
    Vivamus hendrerit, dolor aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis velit,
    faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo.</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus.
    Quisque lobortis.Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa.</p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
 

 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, i works on class selector as well. i had it inside another function.